# What component is this and how can I test it?

Tags: identification

I'm new to electronics. What is this and how can I test it?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a blue camping gas bottle to me but I haven't got the ability to measure it.

Comment: Showing a bit more of the board in your photo gives us a clue of circuit context - and a potential for a better answer.

Answer (score 7):

It is a 1mH power inductor, as you can see from the DC-DC [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/195769/ROHM/BP5053-12.html).

[image]

It should measure as a low resistance and, if you have an inductance meter, somewhere around 100mH.

Comment: Did you go by the BP 5053-12 in the picture background ?!

Comment: @AJN Yes, though it was to be my guess anyway.

Comment: That's some impressive perception! +1 :)

Comment: What is 102? That blue one.

Comment: The value of inductance. 1 + 0 + two more zeroes = 1000\$\mu\$H (1mH)